# TypeError: Cannot read property 'RichEmbed' of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I've Been Searching For A Solutions For This Error But Until Now I Didn't Found Any Solutions And Now Took More Than 2 Days To Find A Solution So I Published My Problem Here So Anybody Can See It And Comment Why The Error Shows ?

**The Problem :** `TypeError: Cannot read property 'RichEmbed' of undefined(18:35)`

**My Code** :

```
1:  module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
2: 
3:      let target = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first());
4:      let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');
5:      let logs = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "⚠server_logs");
6:    
7:      // member.guild.channels.cache.find('⚠server_logs', config.logsChannel);
8:
9:      if (!message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) return message.reply('you don\'t have permissions to use this command!s');
10:
11:      if (!target) return message.reply('please specify a member to ban!');
12:      if (!reason) return message.reply('please specify a reason for this ban!');
13:      if (!logs) return message.reply(`please create a channel called ${config.logsChannel} to log the bans!`);
14:
15:      let embed = new discord.cache.RichEmbed()
16:          .setColor('RANDOM')
17:          .setThumbnail(target.user.avatarURL)
18:          .addField('Banned Member', `${target.user.username} with an ID: ${target.user,id}`)
19:          .addField('Banned By', `${message.author.username} with an ID: ${message.author.id}`)
20:          .addField('Banned Time', message.createdAt)
21:          .addField('Banned At', message.channel)
22:          .addField('Banned Reason', reason)
23:          .addFooter('Banned user information', target.user.displayAvatarURL);
24:
25:      message.channel.send(`${target.user.username} was banned by ${message.author} for ${reason}`);
26:      target.ban(reason);
27:      logs.send(embed);
28:  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 problems with your code:
The first one is that discord is not defined,
and RichEmbed was replaced with MessageEmbed in v12, so you should add this to the top of your code:

```
const discord = require('discord.js'); // defines discord.js
```

and if you are using discord.js v12, replace "new discord.cache.RichEmbed()" with:

```
let embed = new discord.MessageEmbed(); // define the embed you want to use
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
const { RichEmbed } = require ('discord.js');

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

let target = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first());
let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');
let logs = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "⚠server_logs");

// member.guild.channels.cache.find('⚠server_logs', config.logsChannel);

if (!message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) return message.reply('you don\'t have permissions to use this command!s');

if (!target) return message.reply('please specify a member to ban!');
if (!reason) return message.reply('please specify a reason for this ban!');
if (!logs) return message.reply(`please create a channel called ${config.logsChannel} to log the bans!`);

let embed = new RichEmbed()
.setColor('RANDOM')
.setThumbnail(target.user.avatarURL)
.addField('Banned Member', `${target.user.username} with an ID: ${target.user,id}`)
.addField('Banned By', `${message.author.username} with an ID: ${message.author.id}`)
.addField('Banned Time', message.createdAt)
.addField('Banned At', message.channel)
.addField('Banned Reason', reason)
.addFooter('Banned user information', target.user.displayAvatarURL);

message.channel.send(`${target.user.username} was banned by ${message.author} for ${reason}`);
target.ban(reason);
logs.send(embed);
};
```

Comment: Edit : I forgot the new infront of RichEmbed

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have `discord.cache` defined.
If you're using discord.js v12 or higher, use `Discord.MessageEmbed()`. If using v11, use `Discord.RichEmbed()`.

Make sure to add

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
```

at the top.

**Example**

```
const Discord = require("discord.js"); // v12
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setColor("RED")
.setTitle("This is an embed.");
```